# Convert Tex Equation to Image (Math

Tags: svg, mathjax

I'm using MathJax and would like to convert the Tex equation to an svg image. Right now it converts it to SVG source code but that is not useful. How can I covert it to SVG image programmatically? (In a .Net/C# Environment)

Similar to here:

1. https://www.bruot.org/tex2img/
2. https://viereck.ch/latex-to-svg/

Thanks.

Comment: what's the difference between an svg image and SVG source code? SVG is a text format so an SVG image is just SVG source code rendered by something. Is your question just "How do I render SVG in .Net?"

Comment: Take a look at this website: https://viereck.ch/latex-to-svg/. Click on SVG source code on the bottom right. I would like to convert that to just an image file.

Comment: It is an image file, no conversion necessary

Comment: I would like to change this:
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="96.608px" height="33.224px" viewBox="0 -1149.5 5337.6 1835.5"..........
to this:
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIi................

Comment: Then that's the question you should ask. Just base64 encode the data you already have, although you don't really need to, it will generally work just as well if you only encode the # characters.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following... the svg tag has xml data, how is that correlated with the image. Don't know what i'm missing here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247252/discussion-between-robert-longson-and-piris).